# Podman push to quay results in "Requesting bearer token: invalid status code from registry 400 (Bad Request)"

Tags: linux, podman, quay

I'm on Linux (RHEL8) trying to use `podman` to push to an internal quay registry, but I get an error about the "bearer token" when I execute the `podman push`, as shown below:

```
podman login -u="quay_robot_username" -p="quay_robot_password" quay.companydomain.com
Login Succeeded!
```

```
podman push  f8f914cef1ce0cc6314355ae5d16c6d5faf96e595fa1332cf40d26f9c53b9c07   quay.companydomain.com/organization/repository/a890f2e
Getting image source signatures
Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:0c23ed2428e1ef41fdb571789f6968dd47c95135311b1c8bf56462c98581694b at destination: Requesting bearer token: invalid status code from registry 400 (Bad Request)
```

For username and password, I'm using a quay robot that has write permission for the quay repository.

I understand that quay is looking for `Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>` in the http request headers.

It would be nice to see the headers of the http requests generated by `podman push` to verify the presence or absence of the bearer token in the headers.  But, given the error, I'm assuming it's not present.

**Two questions:**

1. How do I get the bearer token - if I don't already have it?

I did create an Oauth application in my quay organization and generated an access token there - which I was able to use successfully in a curl request:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>" https://quay.companydomain.com/api/v1/repository/organization/myrepository/tag/    | jq
```

Will that token work for the `podman push`?

2. Once I have the token, how do I include it in the `podman push` command's http request?

*Note:  I was initiating it from a github action, but to simplify things, I'm just trying to get it working on the command line (I get the same error either way).*